# Android Activity only works if it's declared as main and launcher activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I'm building a music player in android. What I'm trying is to show playlist 
when the app launches and user click on the list item and intent is passed to the android_player activity which plays the song.
But it's not working and when i click on list item app crashes and closes.

But when I declare music_player activity as launcher it works. But I want to show the playlist first and not the music_player.

I have following manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidMusicPlayerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <-- <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> -->
   </activity>
</application>
```

What changes I should make to my manifest file to make it work.

```
AndroidMusicPlayerActivity has following code to receive intent

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                 int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100){
         currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");

         // play selected song
         playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}
```

MainActivity which shows playlist passes following intent

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting listItem index
                int songIndex = position;

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AndroidMusicPlayerActivity.class);
                // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
                setResult(100, in);
                // Closing PlayListView
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Log Cat data, when I click on listitem.

```
04-30 16:17:16.946: D/OpenGLRenderer(3858): Enabling debug mode 0 04-30
16:17:29.958: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3858): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection 
04-30 16:17:30.018: D/OpenGLRenderer(3858): Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

What changes I should make to make this code work.
I'm new to android. Please help.
Thanks!!

Comment: "it crashes and closes" -> post your logcat and point out which line in your snippets it refers to.

Comment: Please post logcat and your java code too...

Comment: @Class Stacker added LogCat data

Comment: We need the logcat output _upon crash_, my friend.

Comment: 04-30 16:25:53.920: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4504): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-30 16:25:54.030: D/OpenGLRenderer(4504): Flushing caches (mode 1)

@ClassStacker that's all there's in the logcat

Comment: When I uncomment intent filter for MusicPlayer activity and comment out intent filter for MainActivity in manifest, app works fine. What am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing something but in your itemClickListener you seem to be calling finish() on your first activity without starting the second.
Surely you need to add a startActivity(in); call.

Comment: When I use startActivity(in); it started the second activity but it's not playing the intended song.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to use the onActivityResult backwards.  If you put the 'currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");   // play selected song
         playSong(currentSongIndex);' in your oncreate for the second activity I think it will do what you want.

Comment: what is your coding in your method  // play selected song
         playSong(currentSongIndex); create just a object of MediaPlayer and create it.Then call mediaplayer.start() It will not stop event after you switch to another activity or you destroy your activiy

Comment: @user2145222 I used Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); in second activity's onCreate() method and extracted songindex and now it works fine.
Do I need onActivityResult() method in my second activity now or I should delete it?

Comment: From what you have said, yes I would remove this code as I don't think it is relevant to what you want.  If you just want to pass simple values, read them out in the oncreate or onstart methods of the new activity having added them as you were.  Well done on getting it working.

Answer (score 0):

why you are making both activity as launcher in manifest? remove it then check.

Comment: I'm only making one MainActivity as launcher activity. But main activity is not launching PlayerActivity.

Comment: you are calling set result method in your lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() } method call startActiviy(); method and pass intent in that.

Comment: When I use startActivity(in); it started the second activity but it's not playing the intended song.